# How do you do drill down reporting in a Win Form [.Net] without 3rd party controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Looks like my only option is to create a mutatant child of the tree view and data grid view,but Im mostly an asp.net developer,and thus my lack of knowledge of all things windows. but Im sure there is an alternate easier solution, so before I go down that ugly path, does anyone know a way to create a drill down report in a winform application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the Crystal Reports viewer that comes with .NET now?

[Introduction to Crystal Reports in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CrystalReportsIntroduction11082005014959AM/CrystalReportsIntroduction.aspx)